VS Code, Golang formatting stubborn situation with switch/case

I am using VSCode 1.87.2, OS is Ubunu 23.10
Using Go extension v0.41.2
I disabled all other extensions for testing purposes
Using go1.21.0 linux/amd64

I write this snippet of code in my *.go Golang files:
switch {
  case myString == "":
    fmt.Println("Empty string")
  case myString == "foo":
    doFoo()
  case myString == "bar":
    fmt.Println("We got bar now!")
  default:
    fmt.Println("Another default")
}

And VS code is formatting it as:
switch {
case myString == "":
  fmt.Println("Empty string")
case myString == "foo":
  doFoo()
case myString == "bar":
  fmt.Println("We got bar now!")
default:
  fmt.Println("Another default")
}

Question, is there a way I conf configure VSCode / Go extension / other in a REASONABLE (i.e. without to have to write my own VS Code extension or hack around unusual odd settings) so that the formatting of the snippet 1 can be preserved?
What I tried:

Tried formatters: gofumpt, gofmt, goimports
Tried disabling all extensions (except go).

Not sure what is wrong.

There is a Go Proverb "Gofmt's style is no one's favorite, yet gofmt is everyone's favorite". I'd strongly suggest you don't fight this; almost all Go code is formatted using gofmt (or a compatible, stricter, standard), and the lack of options is deliberate. See this blog post for a rationale and further info.

I never understood why we indent everything else inside a block, but not case inside switch. It's very common across many languages.

@Brits I'd be glad if you'd read the question before commenting. I specified I tried gofmt too. Thank you.

@JJF I understand that. I'm warning you that the format implemented in gofmt (a part of the standard tooling) is the standard format for Go code; as the blog I linked says "uncontroversial: never have a debate about spacing or brace position ever again!".  You will struggle to find tools that implement different standards (requesting these would be off topic) and I'd strongly suggest that you adopt the standard (there will be a few things you don't like, but the benefits of using the same format as everyone else outweighs this).

@Brits thank you for clarifying. Do you mean that the first snippet, is the format implemented by gofmt, i.e. the standard? And therefore the formatting I would like to have is the non-standard?

@JJF The second "VS Code Formatting" is the Go standard. For example, it is used in Effective Go.

Visual Studio Code does not know Go. As part of the process of setting up you installed a standard Go plugin and that standard Go plugin installed the standard Go language server which is the entity doing all the formatting. It is really recommended to just not ice skate uphill and follow the standard it dictates. Even if it does unforgivable things like indent with tabs.

@Schwern: it is the bit about gofmt that I found most counter-intuitive, too, but I can see some logic if you equate switch + case to an if-else if set of conditionals. The else if's would all be on the same level, the block that is indented matches the statements in the else if block. In that way, switch kind of means if exp := <switch expression>; if exp == <case1> {} else if exp == <case2> {} then the indentation makes sense

@EliasVanOotegem Hey, thanks for trying to explain rather than just telling people to follow the standard. Standards should mean something. However, by that logic the code in for loops wouldn't be indented. You just described a nested if. Indentation is to quickly identify what code is inside a block, Go style violates that. This is all a throwback to ancient C styles when it was closer to being a jump table and the "case" labels weren't indented. Some people don't indent case/when in SQL either.

@schwern: the code in the loops would be indented, same as the code of a case block is. The else if conditions/evaluations aren't indented relative to the surrounding block, or the original if clause. It's got nothing to do with nested it's. Sure it's a common thing in some C styles, and when you ask some older C dev colleague about the reason why that style makes sense to them, you'd get the answer I gave (speaking from experience).

@EliasVanOotegem And the cases depend on the switch, as in switch a { ... }, they should also be indented to show they're part of the switch block. I'm sure you've gotten many explanations. Another one I've gotten is that a switch is not a true block. True, but not illuminating. A style is supposed to make the code easier to understand at a glance: these cases are part of this switch. If it requires a complicated justification it's not helping anyone except maybe the people who have been doing it that way for decades.

@Schwern: I agree that a style is to make code more easy to understand. It's just about different people interpreting/conceptually mapping a switch statement (and its cases) differently. The go AST clearly takes the view that a switch statement contains a slice of case clauses (ie the case clauses constitute the switch clause). Each case clause contains the actual block of statements. For reference the go compiler source  code

Look, I used to indent all case clauses in C, or whatever other language. The go format looked a bit weird at first, but it's a habit. It doesn't hinder readability at all once you get used to it. I looked at the compiler to see what may have informed the style choice, and found that a case clause, in AST terms, is composed from the TypeSwitchStmt node (for example, the Assign Stmt) and the CaseClause node (List []Expr). The entire condition to determine whether or not execute the Block *BlockStmt under the CaseClause is contingent on both the switch statement

@EliasVanOotegem Style is to provide humans with information about the code at a glance. If it only makes sense after you examine the implementation in detail, it isn't working.

@Schwern yes, but not what I said. My point was that even without the explanation and checking the AST, I had already gotten used to the gofmt style. Before that, I was a strong proponent of the Allman style. TL;DR: it's a nit-pick at best, not hard to get used to non-indented case clauses. WRT open-source projects, it's best to have a singular code style so everyone can parse the code quickly, rather than a custom style that requires editor configs to change depending on the project etc...

It is, indeed, the Go style to not indent inside a switch for some reason, possibly a hold over from C styles. For example, this is the style used in Effective Go. In addition, the Go community is generally against changing the style and their tools generally are not configurable. VSCode's own language server and all your mentioned Go tools will follow this style.
However, goformat will let you adjust the style. For example, indent=2 switch enter=1 will give you a more familiar style with 2 character whitespace indentation and switch blocks will be indented.
goformat.exe -style "indent=2 switch enter=1" .\tmp\test.go

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  myString := "foo"

  switch {
    case myString == "":
      fmt.Println("Empty string")
    case myString == "foo":
      fmt.Println("foo")
    case myString == "bar":
      fmt.Println("We got bar now!")
    default:
      fmt.Println("Another default")
  }
}

VSCode can be configured to use goformat. In the Go extension search for "Format Flags" and "Format Tool". You can put your style choices into a file and commit it with your project.

Correction: it is not the "more familiar style" in GoLang terms.  That's the point of gofmt.  Using goformat or other formatters is all well and good if you work on your own code in splendid isolation, but as soon as you work on code with others, either as a team or contributing to an open-source project, individual formatting preferences become a constant drag, which is precisely why GoLang is so opinionated on the matter;  goformat may have been well-intentioned but IMHO it is misguided and should be avoided, certainly not recommended.

@Deltics I didn't recommend it, I answered the question. They can take it or leave it. It's the more familiar style for those who are coming from other languages, and haven't yet drank the kool-aid, what flavor was yours?

@Deltics Most languages have solved the style chaos problem by supplying per-project style config files so people automatically follow the project style. There's even a universal one called EditorConfig. Then should a language choose to, oh I don't know, carry forward obsolete styles like hard-tabs and pretending switch/case is a jump table, those can be fixed by the community. Let me tell you about the 4 character indentation with mixed hard tabs and spaces (1 indent = 4 spaces, 2 indents = hard tab, 3 = tab + 4 spaces) that used to be the Perl standard. Yikes.

per project config is not a "solution", it's a sticking-plaster.  It does not address the fact that different people work on different projects so switching between projects potentially (in that case) means having to also adjust to different styles, unless only working on projects in an environment where a consistent style is enforced.  But that still leaves the problem of settling on what that "consistent style" should be, and the potential for it to be changed (under the guise of "improved"), so leaving the door open for on-going debate and arguments.  As I say, not a "solution".

@Deltics I jump languages and projects a lot. Default styles are useful, but are often flawed and will never satisfy everyone. I prefer a style with well-articulated changes with an automated style fixer. Small differences in what I write don't matter, they will automatically adjust and I'll come to learn the new style. As for "leaving the door open for on-going debate and arguments", I find the issue is often that people don't understand how styles work and instead argue for familiarity and consistency as the goal; they are not goals but means to a goal. Those arguments will never end.

"Those arguments will never end." exactly!!  There is one scenario in which those arguments HAVE been put to an end for good... in teams using golang who have adopted the gomft standard and resisted the temptation to try to make golang look like some other language with which they might also be familiar. :)

@Deltics Yet here we are arguing about it. A one-true-style approach treats style as arbitrary; the most important thing is that everyone is using the same style. Style isn't arbitrary, it has a lot of utility if you understand it, and OTS takes that away. It's not about trying to treat Go like another language, tho the Go switch style is C circa 1995. To stop the endless style arguments, and allow flexibility, a project starts with the default style and codifies its modifications as a formatter config. If your project can't agree on formatter config changes, how do they agree on anything?

of course, any team has disagreements and ways and means of resolving them and reaching consensus.  By adopting idiomatic gofmt standards, one source of disagreement is eliminated, allowing teams to focus on reaching agreement on more important matters.  Working in a golang team where we have never discussed formatting (other than to understand the role of gofmt), alongside Java teams who spend an absurd amount of time arguing about, debating, ratifying and policing/enforcing "enterprise format" standards, while we get on with work that matters to our users/customers.

VS Code is not formatting your code.  At least not directly.
The GoLang extension is responsible for formatting and will format your code whenever you save a file. By default, it uses gofmt, the ubiquitous and highly opinionated formatter adopted by most Go developers.
Yes, the extension provides a setting to enable this to be configured to use an alternate formatter if you insist. But IMHO, the best advice is to learn to work with and appreciate the standard formatting, not fight it.
As you have found, some people find some aspects of the formatting that gofmt applies irritating to varying degrees. I am sure you will encounter more of these as you gain experience with GoLang. All I can say is that the irritation will fade.
In teams, the value of the time, arguments and frustration saved by the (almost total) elimination of "personal style" that gofmt achieves is not to be underestimated.  Neither is the extent to which it is a significant factor in making it easier to pick up GoLang code written by virtually anybody without having to first adjust to their individual style layered over the top of the language syntax.
All is not (necessarily) lost
In cases that you find particularly problematic, there is usually some degree of flexibility within the constraints of the standard formatting.  For example, in the case of a switch/case, gofmt will preserve (at most) one line of whitespace separation between cases, so you could use:
switch {
case myString == "":
  fmt.Println("Empty string")

case myString == "foo":
  doFoo()

case myString == "bar":
  fmt.Println("We got bar now!")

default:
  fmt.Println("Another default")
}

It's up to you whether you find that to be an improvement or not. :)
But it is an example of where gofmt allows some flexibility.
This flexibility can be useful in other ways beyond individual preference and can become a "tool" in its own right.  For example, within a single switch you could mix/match whitespace separation to "group" related cases if you find that useful in a specific instance, e.g.:
switch {
case myString == "foo":
  doFoo()
case myString == "bar":
  fmt.Println("We got bar now!")

case myString == "":
  fmt.Println("Empty string")
default:
  fmt.Println("Another default")
}

Again, whether that is an "improvement" is largely subjective, but at least gofmt won't get in your way on this one. :)
